# SSRS 2012 export to excel showing 1 and 2 top left

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I have an issue with my hidden items when exporting to excel. I basically have a text box just above a rectangle (the rectangle contains a graph), so I set the rectangle to be hidden on run time and set the visibility toggle to the text box just above it. I do this for about 3 individual text boxes and rectangles.

ok, so here is the problem, when I export to excel, the expand and collapse tick box (that one that shows the plus or minus), is gone and all I have to toggle with is a 1 and 2 at the top left of excel, but that changes the state of all the items in the sheet and the individual toggles are gone.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Kind Regards
Quinell